# jQuery Mobile: $.mobile is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm trying to parse a remote JSON file by using jQuery, but I get "$.mobile is undefined" error.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min"></script>    
<script>
$.support.cors = true;
$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data)
    {
        alert ("Ok");
    })  
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? Both "jquery-1.9.1.min.js" and "jquery-1.9.1.min.js" exist and I didn't modify them.

Comment: Make sure  this is the right path to the jQuery mobile file...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typo. Change

```
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>    
//                                     ^^^
```

Comment: Added the above to make the change  easier to spot.